# Close the main window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a code that creates two windows after execution. It would look something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
def initialization ():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    instance1 = Windows1(root)
    root.mainloop()

class Windows1:
    def __init__(self, master):
      self.master= master
      self.master.title('main window')
      self.master.geometry('400x200')
      self.btn = Button(self.master,text='push here',command = self.function) 
      self.btn.grid(row = 2 , column= 0)

    def function(self):
       windows2 = Toplevel(self.master) 
       instance2 = win2(self.master)

class win2:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('window2')
        self.master.geometry('400x600')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    initialization()
```

If you press the command button located in the main window, a second window opens
I would like to know if I can close the main window, without also closing the second window when pressing the command button.
For this purpose, I tried to modify the function attached to the command button through the root.destroy() command, but I get an error every time I try to create a new main window, because the root.mainloop executed in the first function cannot be executed twice in  the same script. As an idea, I think I need to find a command to change the main window from the initialized one to the one opened afterwards (from windows1 to win2), but I don't know how I could do this.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that seems to work.
I declare the root global variable and use the root.destroy() command within a function.
The resulting code would look something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
def initialization ():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    instance1 = Windows1(root)
    root.mainloop()

class Windows1:
    def __init__(self, master):
      self.master= master
      self.master.title('first window')
      self.master.geometry('400x200')
      self.btn = Button(self.master,text='push here',command = self.function) 
      self.btn.grid(row = 2 , column= 0)

    def function(self):
       root.destroy()
       root1 = Tk()
       instance2 = win2(root1)
    
       
class win2:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('second window')
        self.master.geometry('400x600')



        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    initialization()
```

Comment: Glad you solved problem. I had this root.destroy() in function, but forgotten TopLevel. Thanks!